# Need a regular expression to control maximum limit for a text box

Tags: regex

I have a text area field in my form and I want to have a validation in place for that field. If the user enters more than 5000 characters to that field(any type of characters including blank space and special characters) and hit on next button, it should give a error message. Can this be done by using regular expression?

Comment: What language is it? What did you try?

Comment: Search for this on Google: "html input max length"

Answer (score 0):

A regex that stands for: "Matches anything up to 5000 characters"

Would simply be:

```
^.{0,5000}$
```

However, depending on the language you're using to program you might find better alternatives than using regex (especially for Web Languages).

Comment: Not necessarily. 5000 characters might include newlines as well which your dot does not cover. Better would be `[\s\S]{0,5000}`.

Comment: The question is vague and doesn't specify much about the "field" nor the language he's using. He could use ^.{0,5000}$ with the /s option or indeed use ^[\s\S]{0,5000}$.
But the question isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the expression ^[\s\S]{0,5000}$  which worked fine for me.

Thanks!